# Cannot extend hard drive partition

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have the partition that I want to extend onto "Unallocated" (in Windows 7 the color-code indicator above is black).  The volume that I want to extend is formatted correctly (NTFS) as indicated by the official Microsoft directions.  The volume that I want to extend on was originally named "RECOVERY" and is ~10GB. When I right click the volume I want to extend, the "Extend Volume" option is not clickable. I have tried reformatting the "RECOVERY" partition in several different manners, to no avail. Help?

Comment: Is the 'RECOVERY' partition adjacent to the partition you are trying to extend?  If not, you won;t be able to.

Comment: Yes. There are 3 partitions: OEM -- UNALLOCATED -- (C:).
Unallocated is right beside C:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to extend a partition where your system files are located? I've tried this a little while back (reducing the size of my data partition to make room for programs) but to no avail. I believe I read somewhere that you *can't* extend that particular partition with the W7 Disk Management utility. You'll likely have to look for a different piece of software (e.g. Partition Magic) to do that.

Comment: the partition i am trying to extend does have my system files on it. partition magic will work? i guess I'll give it a go

Comment: finally got around to it. it was a breeze. thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked out. :)